# Any SMTP client for Windows that supports SSL and SMTP server authentification?

Tags: windows, command-line, smtp

I am looking for a command line mailers which support SSL and authentication.
So far I tried '[blat](http://www.blat.net/)' but it doesn't support SSL.

Any suggestions?

OS is Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[`swaks`](http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/) supports both - it needs [Perl](http://win32.perl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page#Installing_Perl_on_Windows_for_the_First_Time.3F) to work, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SendEmail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/):

> SendEmail is a lightweight, command line SMTP email client. If you
>   have the need to send email from a command line, this free program is
>   perfect: simple to use and feature rich. It was designed to be used in
>   bash scripts, batch files, Perl programs and web sites, but is quite
>   adaptable and will likely meet your requirements. SendEmail is written
>   in Perl and is unique in that it requires NO MODULES. It has an
>   intuitive and flexible set of command-line options, making it very
>   easy to learn and use.

[image]